# Select a file from a list with a specific filename?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm trying to run a block of tasks only when a specific filename is found in a directory. Here's what I have so far:

```yaml
- name: Get downloaded files
  ansible.builtin.find:
    paths: "{{ temp_dir.path }}"
    patterns: "*"
  register: temp_files
```

I want to run some tasks against the file `FileReferences.csv` if it exists, but I don't know how to filter the whole `temp_files` list down to just the object with the filename `FileReferences.csv`.

I think this should just require the right ansible/jinja2 filter on the `temp_files` list but I can't figure out which filter to use or how to use it.

More context (if necessary): Once I filter down to the file I want, I'll use the `community.general.read_csv` module to get data from the CSV, then based on that data I'll post information to a REST API. I think I can get all that figured out, it's just filtering the list down to one item that I need help with.

Comment: Do you test the existence of the file *FileReferences.csv* on the controller only? Or, do you test it on all targets?

Comment: controller only. In the previous task it was just downloaded from S3 so it only exists in the local temp dir

Answer (score 1):

The [testing paths](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-paths) on the controller is easy. For example, given the variables

```yaml
  temp_dir:
    path: /tmp
  csv_file: "{{ temp_dir.path }}/FileReferences.csv"
```

and the CSV file on the controller

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/FileReferences.csv 
k1;k2;k3
v1a;v1b;v1c
v2a;v2b;v2c
v3a;v3b;v3c
```

The below block will execute if the file exists

```yaml
    - block:
        - community.general.read_csv:
            path: "{{ csv_file }}"
            delimiter: ";"
          register: file_references
        - debug:
            var: file_references.list|to_yaml
      when: csv_file is exists
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  file_references.list:
    - {k1: v1a, k2: v1b, k3: v1c}
    - {k1: v2a, k2: v2b, k3: v2c}
    - {k1: v3a, k2: v3b, k3: v3c}
```

The block will be skipped if the file is missing.

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    temp_dir:
      path: /tmp
    csv_file: "{{ temp_dir.path }}/FileReferences.csv"

  tasks:

    - block:
        - community.general.read_csv:
            path: "{{ csv_file }}"
            delimiter: ";"
          register: file_references
        - debug:
            var: file_references.list|to_yaml
      when: csv_file is exists
```